# Privileges not displaying properly?

Tags: feature-request, privileges

My reputation = 76. Simple.
Next privilege = 100: create new chat rooms. Simple.

I pull up the privileges page and see this.
[image: Next privilege: edit community wiki, 76/100]

Is this intentional or is this an error?

Edit: I just realized that they are both the same rep level :P. Is it possible that the page could be made to display both?

Comment: +1 for not realising it was both. I make those kind of mistakes all the time. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, this is intentional. All users should see that if their reputation is under 100. If I am wrong, users will see either "Create New Chat Rooms" or "Edit Community Wiki". For your request, I can't do anything for it. Only moderators or those people controlling Stack Overflow (its producers and updaters/programmers) can say if that request will be denied or granted. I think it is possible, but I can't be sure of that.